What are the criteria for selecting CTs in a power system?
In powersystems how can we select CT's whith dinite sepecifications?
for Metering and protection systems

Acc. to IEEE and IEC Standards

https://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_iec61869-2%7Bed1.0%7Db.pdf

Selection will follow the same procedure as any other selection:

Write a specification:

Primary rating.
Secondary rating.
Primary conductor size and shape.
Maximum size.
Insulation voltage rating.
Electrical standards compliance (CE, UL, etc.)
Environmental ratings.
Warranty considerations.
Availability and lead time.
Business record of the vendor.



Then start shopping.

A nice answer for homework!
